# Error: No such user when trying to remove permission for file or folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm using google-app-scripts to revoke permissions to files and folders of google drive, i loop through my google drive files and folders and when i find that user has an access to the file i try to revoke it, but then exception: "No such user" occurs, i can't find any reason for why would that happen.

```
function run() {
    var emailsToRevoke = ["EmailA", "EmailB"];
    revoke(emailsToRevoke);
}

function revoke(emails){
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();

  emails.forEach(function(email){
    try {
      while(files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();

        if(file.getAccess(email) !== DriveApp.Permission.NONE) {
          file.revokePermissions(email)
        }

        var editors = file.getEditors();
        var viewers = file.getViewers();

        console.log("Checking Permission for: " + file)

        for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
          if(editors[i].getEmail() === email) {
            console.log("Revoking Permission to " + file.getName() + " for: " + email )
            file.removeEditor(email)
          };
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < viewers.length; i++) {
          if(viewers[i].getEmail() === email) {
            console.log("Revoking Permission to " + file.getName() + " for: " + email )
            file.removeViewer(email)
          };
        }

        doubleCheckUser(file, email)
      }

      while(folders.hasNext()) {
        var folder = folders.next();


        if(folder.getAccess(email) !== DriveApp.Permission.NONE) {
          folder.revokePermissions(email)
        }

        var editors = folder.getEditors();
        var viewers = folder.getViewers();

        console.log("Checking Permission for: " + folder)

        for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
          if(editors[i].getEmail() === email) {
            console.log("Revoking Permission to " + folder.getName() + " for: " + email )
            folder.removeEditor(email)
          };
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < viewers.length; i++) {
          if(viewers[i].getEmail() === email) {
            console.log("Revoking Permission to " + folder.getName() + " for: " + email )
            folder.removeViewer(email)
          };
        }

        doubleCheckUser(folder, email);
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.error("Error During Revoking Access Process: " + error)
    }   
  });
}

function doubleCheckUser(objectToCheck, email) {
  try {
    var access = objectToCheck.getAccess(email)
    if(access !== DriveApp.Permission.NONE) {
      console.warn("Access to: " + objectToCheck.getName() + " has not been revoked properly. Current Access: " + access)
    }
  } catch(error) {
    console.error("Error Double Checking If User: " + email + " Was Removed Properly From: " + objectToCheck.getName())
  }
}
```

I'm sure that the email has an access to the files as i log it in doubleCheckUser(), i'm also sure that the email is valid.

The way it's triggered is simply by user adding emails to the emailsToRevoke array and then choosing the run function in the google scripts UI and pressing run.

My question is, what do i do wrong and how can i solve this issue? At the end of the day all i need is revoke the access so don't hesitate if you know a better way of going about it.

Edit --- 
Note that the drive has **a lot of files** in it (definitely above 1000 files and folders)

Comment: Can I ask you about the part of script that the error of ``No such user" occurs`` occurs?

Comment: it happens in the moment of revoking permissions e.g file.revokePermissions(email)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation. Can I ask you about the flow for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm sorry for late response but i had to move to another thing for a while. If it comes to flow what you are seeing is pretty much the whole script, i updated it with few details.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the information of the file when the error occurs?

Comment: For anyone encountering this same error, in my case it was because my script was attempting to revoke permissions for a user who did not have permissions. Make sure the user actually has view/write/comment permissions before trying to revoke them.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, it seems that although the documentation supports removing a user by their email address, the code requires a drive user object (rather than an email address string...) I solved it by using the following code, hope this helps someone:

```
const fileIds = ["abc123","123abc"]//array of file ids to have permissions revoked from
var emailAddr = "email address you want to revoke"

revoke(emailAddr)

function revoke(em){
  Logger.log("Revoke "+em)
  for (var f in fileIds){
    Logger.log("FILE ID "+f)
    for (var loop=0; loop<1;loop++){ // sometimes users are repeated - this step ensures the list is checked again if the target email address is found
      for(i in DriveApp.getFileById(fileIds[f]).getViewers()){
        Logger.log(DriveApp.getFileById(fileIds[f]).getViewers()[i].getEmail())
        if(DriveApp.getFileById(fileIds[f]).getViewers()[i].getEmail()==em){
          Logger.log("rem "+DriveApp.getFileById(fileIds[f]).getViewers()[i].getEmail())
          DriveApp.getFileById(fileIds[f]).revokePermissions(DriveApp.getFileById(fileIds[f]).getViewers()[i])
          loop-- //target email address found, iterate loop one more time to check again
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sam